# Detail view to show only in table area of screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to be able to show the detail view of a table, but not push a new screen, but only show the detail view where the table is.

What's the best way of setting this up.. if it is actually possible?

```
------------------------------------
|                                  |
|           nav bar or tool bar    |
------------------------------------
|                                  |
|        this area stays static    |
|                                  |
------------------------------------                ---------------------------------
|                                  |                |                               |
|                                  |                |                               |
|                                  |                |                               |
|           table…                 |                |  new uitableview pushed.      |
|                                  | cell clicked-> | only the table area changes   |
|                                  |                |                               |
|                                  |                |                               |
|                                  |                |                               |
------------------------------------                ---------------------------------
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      | < tab bar
|      |      |      |      |      |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: I will suggest you create two tableView one over other and show/hide based on cell selection.

Comment: how would i handle the tableview delegates in that case?

Comment: Create a delegate and two different tableViewController class and add your table view related to tableViewController and set the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an effect similar to pushing a UIViewController I guess you could animate the tableview out and animate the new view into position at the same time. I don't think there's a way to do it using the actual UINavigationController mechanism, as it replaces the current view on the UINavigationController's stack with the new viewcontroller's view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two methods:

1. Insert the `uitableView` into a `UIView`, this way you will always have reference to a container which holds the uitable view. Also you need to just manage the frame sizes of the child `subviews` of this table view. In your case it would be the first `uitableview` and on button click the next subview can be added using the reference of the `parent container`.
2. Alternatively you can have a macro which has the positions of the `uitableview's frame` with respect to the parent UIView. On inserting another subview you can set the frame therby giving an impression of overlaying above the base `uitableview`.

Comment: I would personally prefer first method, since it removes the headache of positioning the new subviews, you have to just add them at location (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Just have another view on top of the table view and make it hidden.  Set the contents and unhide it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion of resolving this is to use a `UINavigationController` that doesn't have its nav bar showing and doesnt fill the screen. So, your static areas are just plain `UIView`s, but your table view is actually inside a `UINavigationController`, but seems like it is a normal table - as the navigation bar is hidden.

This means you would push the "dynamic" content to the `UINavigationController` and that would animate that section of the screen, but the rest of the screen would remain static.

Comment: I think a UINavigationController has to fill the whole screen

Comment: No it doesn't. Its a common, false misconception. Normally, they are - but they don't have to be.